# Odoo connector filter by many2one field

Tags: php, odoo, connector

i'm using this [connector class](https://github.com/tejastank/openerp-php-connector) to get data from product model by internal category where internal category is many2one field. This is a piece of my script that i have try so far

```
  $rpc->searchread( array( array('categ_id','=','663' ) ),"product.product",array('categ_id','display_name','lst_price','name','taxes_id','weight'),0,100);
```

Is anyone ever using a connector class to get a data filtered by many2one field. Please help me to solve this problem. Thanks